# ReactNative - How to instantly update view

Tags: react-native, view, state

I tried to hide the current screen when the app is in background ; I currently use the "AppState" to detect when the app is in background (or comes to foreground) and force a layer to appear on top of the view.

By now I'm stuck by 2 ReactNative limitations:

- First, AppState on Android has only `background` and no `inactive` state. So, the app couldn't apply new state *before* going to background (only when coming to foreground).
- Second, the asynchronous working way of "setState". Updates are not instantly applied.

As a result, with a snippet like that:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {AppState, Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const App: () => Node = () => {
  const appState = React.useRef(AppState.currentState);
  const [appStateVisible, setAppStateVisible] = React.useState(appState.current);
  const [lockVisible, setLockVisible] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
      if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
        console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
        setLockVisible(true);
      }
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log('AppState', appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>Current Content</Text>
      </View>
      {lockVisible && (
        <View style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: 0,
          backgroundColor: '#f00',
        }}>
          <Text>LOCKED !</Text>
          <Button title={'OPEN'} onPress={() => {setLockVisible(false)}} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

When coming from `background` AppState to `active`, the *lock* view appears, but it's not instantly effective, the current view behind is visible for a little time...

How can I improve that to avoid any "blink", and be sure that the current content isn't visible when coming from `background` AppState ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it didn't blink anymore if I change the state on the `background` event instead of the `come back to foreground` event...

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', nextAppState => {
      if (appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
        console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
      }
      if (nextAppState === 'active') { // <- here is the "fix"
        setLockVisible(true);
      }
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log('AppState', appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: will it work on other pages? I've tried but it's not working